# HTML5 Gamepad API TypeError

Tags: javascript, html, gamepad-api

I'm trying to write some code to get a gamepad and list the axes' position:

```
window.addEventListener("gamepadconnected", (e) => {
                console.log("Gamepad connected at index %d: %s. %d buttons, %d axes.",
                    e.gamepad.index, e.gamepad.id,
                    e.gamepad.buttons.length, e.gamepad.axes.length);
            });
            const [gp] = navigator.getGamepads()[0]
            console.log(gp.axes)
```

and get an `Uncaught TypeError: object null is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))` .

Would really appreciate help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getGamepads` returns `sequence<Gamepad?>`. You're using [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) syntax to unpack it into a variable.

```
const [gp] = navigator.getGamepads()[0]
```

This doesn't work because you're trying to unpack `getGamepads()[0]` which is a `Gamepad` object, not a `sequence`. Try this:

```
const [gp] = navigator.getGamepads();
```

If you don't want to use destructuring assignment syntax:

```
const gp = navigator.getGamepads()[0];
```